# random reading on very large files with fgets seems to bring Windows caching at it's limits

Tags: c, windows, caching, 64-bit, large-files

I have written a C/C++-program for Windows 7 - 64bit that works on very large files. In the final step it reads lines from an input-file (10GB+) and writes them to an output file. The access to the input-file is random, the writing is sequential.
EDIT: Main reason for this approach is to reduce RAM usage.

What I basically do in the reading part is this: (Sorry, very shortened and maybe buggy)

```
void seekAndGetLine(char* line, size_t lineSize, off64_t pos, FILE* filePointer){
  fseeko64(filePointer, pos, ios_base::beg);
  fgets(line, lineSize, filePointer);
}
```

Normally this code is fine, not to say fast, but under some very special conditions it gets very slow. The behaviour doesn't seem to be deterministic, since the performance drops occure on different machines at other parts of the file or even don't occure at all. It even goes so far, that the program totally stops reading, while there are no disc-operations.

Another sympthom seems to be the used RAM. My process keeps it's RAM steady, but the RAM used by the System grows sometimes very large. After using some RAM-Tools I found out, that the Windows Mapped File grows into several GBs. This behaviour also seems to depend on the hardware, since it occure on different machines at different parts of the process.

As far as I can tell, this problem doesn't exist on SSDs, so it definitely has something to do with the responsetime of the HDD.

My guess is that the Windows Caching gets somehow "wierd". The program is fast as long as the cache does it's work. But when Caching goes wrong, the behaviour goes either into "stop reading" or "grow cache size" and sometimes even both. Since I'm no expert for the windows caching algorithms, I would be happy to hear an explanation. Also, is there any way to get Windows out of C/C++ to manipulate/stop/enforce the caching.

Since I'm hunting this problem for a while now, I've already tried some tricks, that didn't work out:

- filePointer = fopen(fileName, "rbR"); //Just fills the cache till the RAM is full
- massive buffering of the read/write, to stop getting the two into each others way

Thanks in advance

Comment: Randomly reading small bits here and there from a file doesn't seem like a very good idea. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Did you try memory-mapping the file?

Comment: Just an aside, there's no reason to use `char*&` over `char*` and it just makes it more confusing.

Comment: @Joey Does not seems a very good idea memory-mapping a multi-gigabyte file.

Comment: Memory mapping big files is no issue. Migth have to work with the window to get the relevant parts available though.

Comment: @lvella, you don't have to map the whole file at once, just a small window into it.

Comment: @Ivella: They said they're on a 64-bit system so unless it's a multi-exabyte file or something it shouldn't really be a problem.

Comment: The files are too large to memory map the whole file. And since I can't predict the window from which I will be reading next, I also can't memory map parts of the file. Also the used up RAM is an issue. The whole point of the algorithm is to keep the RAM usage low.

Answer (score 3):

Truly random access across a huge file is the worst possible case for any cache algorithm.  It *may* be best to turn off as much caching as possible.

There are multiple levels of caching:

- the CRT library (since you're using the f- functions)
- the OS and filesystem
- probably onboard the drive itself

If you replace your I/O calls via the f- functions in the CRT with the comparable ones in the Windows API (e.g., CreateFile, ReadFile, etc.) you can eliminate the CRT caching, which may be doing more harm than good.  You can also warn the OS that you're going to be doing random accesses, which affects its caching strategy.  See options like [`FILE_FLAG_RANDOM_ACCESS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and possibly [`FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

You'll need to experiment and measure.

You might also have to reconsider how your algorithm works.  Are the seeks truly random?  Can you re-sequence them, perhaps in batches, so that they're in order?  Can you limit access to a relatively small region of the file at a time?  Can you break the huge file into smaller files and then work with one piece at a time?  Have you checked the level of fragmentation on the drive and on the particular file?

Comment: Good points and I'm probably trying the Windows API functions. But the FILE_FLAG_RANDOM_ACCESS just seems another way like fopen(fileName, "rbR") to tell Windows that it will be a random access to the file. This works partially since it stops the blockage, but it also increases RAM usage very much and that isn't acceptable for me.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the larger picture of what your application does, you could possibly take a different approach - maybe something like this:

1. decide which lines you need from the input file and store the
   line numbers in a list
2. sort the list of line numbers
3. read through the input file once, in order, and pull out the lines
   you need (better yet, seek to next line and grab it, especially when there's big gaps)
4. if the list of lines you're grabbing is small enough, you can store
   them in memory for reordering before output, otherwise, stick them
   in a smaller temporary file and use that file as input for your
   current algorithm to reorder the lines for final output

It's definitely a more complex approach, but it would be much kinder to your caching subsystem, and as a result, could potentially perform significantly better.

Comment: I think sorting can be efficient if some reads are local. Another thing that might work is some kind of prefetching scheme where you access areas that you are soon going to read in some non blocking way so you can have multiple outstanding page requests going at the same time. This is just speculation though, as always, test and measure is the best approach.